# Checkbox does not reflect its checked value for the first time

Tags: javascript, c#, checkbox

```
void btnSave_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    HtmlInputCheckBox chkUpdate = (HtmlInputCheckBox)rptVersions.Items[i].FindControl("chkUpdate");

    if (chkUpdate.Checked)
    {
       /* some code */
    }

}
```

aspx code:

C#

```
   void btnSave_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
   {            
        HtmlInputCheckBox chkUpdate = (HtmlInputCheckBox)rptVersions.Items[i].FindControl("chkUpdate");

        if (chkUpdate.Checked)
        {
           /* some code */
        }

    }
```

aspx

```
<input type="checkbox" versionid='<%#Eval("VersionId") %>' class="checkbox" runat="server" id="chkUpdate" />
```

js

```
$('.checkbox').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('versionid') == '<%=qryStrVersion%>' && '<%=qryStrVersion%>' != '') {
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
            }
            else
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        });
```

the value of chkUpdate is always false if save button is clicked for the first time.But it is working fine if i click more than once.Can anybody help?

Comment: When does your Javascript run on page load ? Also is the checkbox checked when you click save or is this done via the javascript?

Comment: It is done via javascript itself

Answer (score 1):

It is likely failing because `Eval("VersionId")` and `<%=qryStrVersion%>` are not the exact same. Debug your page and check the values of both of those to see if they are the same.

I ran this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kzebryj/1/) and by the looks of it, if those two values are not the same, the checkbox won't be checked when the page is loaded the first time.

Comment: it is iterating and as soon as qryStrVersion value becomes equal to VersionId the checkbox is checked but in server side it still shows unchecked for the first time

Answer (score 0):

I did not used if(!ispostback) due to which grid was binding twice on single action call.
Thanx everyone!